# Python3: Does mysql db connection need to be explicitly closed in function?

Tags: python, mysql, database, python-3.x, pymysql

Do you have to close mysql (pymysql) connection explicitly within a function in python3, or can you let python3 take care of it automatically as it gets out of scope.

Answer (score 3):

If an object goes out of scope, it doesn't mean Python will call `.close()` on it. `pymysql` does do some cleanup (closing the socket) in the `__del__` method of a connection object ([source](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py)) but I wouldn't rely on it - in particular because it only closes the socket and doesn't communicate to MySQL that the connection is being closed (which is what `.close()` does).

As such it's better to be explicit and close the connection yourself. This also means you know exactly when the connection is closed.